# How to use a tag/facet in metrics monitor in datadog?

Tags: tags, metrics, datadog

I added a custom span tag through code to use a custom tag/facet to filter out specific http requests in datadog:

```
if span, ok := tracer.SpanFromContext(c); ok {
    span.SetTag("someTag", someTagValue)
}
```

In Traces sub-section of APM section, if we click on any http request the tag is appearing with its value as well. I added it as a facet to make it accessible.
[image]

I am defining a metrics monitor and trying to use that tag/facet. In "from" section, the tag/facet does not appear in the list to query those requests. Is there a way to use/add such custom tag/facet in metrics monitor? Are the options in "from" section pre-defined?
[image]

Other datadog sections I have already explored:
In APM monitors, in "Trace Analytics" section, I am able to access that tag/facet. However, this section does not capture same metrics like requests/sec, errors per requests/sec etc.